# Debugging forked child in an anti-debug protected crackme

Tags: linux, anti-debugging, radare2, crackme

I am interested in the anti-debugging method implemented in the crackme called [trace-p](http://crackmes.de/users/taviso/trace_p/). A child process is forked, which communicates with the parent using int3 instructions. I would like to debug the child. gdb has `set follow-fork-mode`, however gdb does not recognize the file as executable (probably because of deleted sections related information). With radare2 I can disassemble and even debug, but I do not know how to follow the child after the fork takes place. I want to do this because the child contains instructions like:

```
0x0804898a    jmp dword [edx*4 + 0x8049334]
```

I want to stop there and examining edx, in order to see where the jump takes.

I am interested in any tool or method which is able to debug the child process.

Answer (score 6):

Use `dbg.forks=true` to stop the debugger when a fork happens. and then just use `dp` to list and select the pid you want to follow.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing with radare2 is to make sure that you're running the latest [git version](https://github.com/radare/radare2).

To get help about commands in radare2, you can use the `?` character. For help about configuration variables, you can use `e??` (since `e?` would give you help about how to use them, not list them). Since there are many variables, you can filter them with the internal grep command : `~`.

```
[0x00000000]> e??dbg
          dbg.args: Set the args of the program to debug
       dbg.backend: Select the debugger backend
           dbg.bep: break on entrypoint (loader, entry, constructor, main)
      dbg.bpinmaps: Force breakpoints to be inside a valid map
        dbg.bpsize: Size of software breakpoints
        dbg.btalgo: Select backtrace algorithm
       dbg.btdepth: Depth of backtrace
         dbg.clone: Stop execution if new thread is created
         dbg.execs: Stop execution if new thread is created
        dbg.follow: Follow program counter when pc > core->offset + dbg.follow
         dbg.forks: Stop execution if fork() is done (see dbg.threads)
          dbg.libs: If set stop when loading matching libname
       dbg.profile: Path to RRunProfile file
 dbg.shallow_trace: While tracing, avoid following calls outside specified range
          dbg.slow: Show stack and regs in visual mode in a slow but verbose mode
        dbg.status: Set cmd.prompt to '.dr*' or '.dr*;drd;sr PC;pi 1;s-'
        dbg.swstep: Force use of software steps (code analysis+breakpoint)
       dbg.threads: Stop all threads when debugger breaks (see dbg.forks)
         dbg.trace: Trace program execution (see asm.trace)
     dbg.trace.tag: Trace tag
        dbg.unlibs: If set stop when unloading matching libname
[0x00000000]>
```

You could aslo have use `e dbg.<tab>`, since there is autocompletion.

Obviously, the variale you're looking for is `dbg.fork`, to set it to true: this will stop the process when it encounters a `fork()`. You can the change the pid with a `d`-command:

```
[0x00000000]> d?~process
| dH [handler]            Transplant process to a new handler
| do                      Open process (reload, alias for 'oo')
| dp[?]                   List, attach to process or thread id
| dx[?]                   Inject and run code on target process (See gs)

[0x00000000]> dp?
|Usage: dp # Process commands
| dp                  List current pid and childrens
| dp             List children of pid
| dp*                 List all attachable pids
| dp=            Select pid
| dp-            Dettach select pid
| dpa            Attach and select pid
| dpe                 Show path to executable
| dpf                 Attach to pid like file fd // HACK
| dpk    Send signal to process
| dpn                 Create new process (fork)
| dpnt                Create new thread (clone)
| dpt                 List threads of current pid
| dpt            List threads of process
| dpt=        Attach to thread

[0x00000000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Radare2 has a configuration variable `dbg.follow.child` which is equivalent to `set follow-fork-mod`.

```
 e??~fork
    dbg.follow.child: Continue tracing the child process on fork. By default the parent process is traced
```

Set it to debug the child process with the command

```
e dbg.follow.child = true
```

or when launching radare with `-e` :

```
r2 -e dbg.follow.child=true -d ./my_binary
```